# Java : reading lines of text from a binary file, with DataInputStream.readLine() deprecated

Tags: java, file-io, io

i am making a Java program that reads a binary file, and this binary file contains lines of text (strings that end with a \n, not \0), among other things (binary data, and even images). I am using a DataInputStream to read the binary data, and its readLine() method looks like exactly what i need to read the lines of text, however it is deprecated, and the official documentation suggests replacing the DataInputStream itself with a BufferedReader if need to read strings in a file. Which is not suitable for my file at all since BufferedReader doesn't read binary data.

So my question is : what do i do ? I can see some "solutions", like using both a DataInputStream and a BufferedReader concurrently, or creating a temporary BufferedReader each time i need to read a string, but they seem very messy and probably unsafe, so i was wondering if there is a simpler way to read both binary data and lines of text.

Comment: Why is your binary data in _lines_?

Comment: I assume that the binary is a valid file format of another type but you just want to read it as binary? If so, then you first need to parse it to the correct file type before you attempt to read individual lines because each and every file format works differently.

Comment: It is a format that was made for a game, containing all the data needed by the game (so there is no "correct" way to parse it, if anything the correct way to parse it is what i am trying to to implement). The game itself is written in C, and it just happened that terminating the strings with \n instead of \0 made it easier to read them with the C I/O library.

Comment: So it is a non-standard binary format. You have to read the bytes and interpret them according to the given format in your own implementation. A BufferedReader is not suitable because it is for text only. The connection between bytes and text is the InputStreamReader in conjunction with a character encoding but it treats the whole file as text not only parts of it.

Comment: If you want to read only the string parts you can implement a class similar to InputStreamReader. On the one end it reads the bytes and on the other side it is a reader which can be wrapped in a BufferedReader.